# GatewayTimeout during call the stored procedure in Azure Logic App

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps

I have stored procedure that should return some data. 
When I call this procedure using MS SQL Management studio, the call takes 1-3 seconds.
When I call this procedure using 'Execute stored procedure' or 'Execure SQL Query' actions in Azure logic app, I get **GatewayTimeout** responce after two minutes of waiting.

[image: GatewayTimeout]

Comment: There is an inbuilt timeout in logic apps of 120 seconds. From what I can read, you need to set the setting to Asynchronous.  However, you also need to get a 202 accepted code back to logic apps from the database.  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#async-pattern).  That's the part I'm trying to work out.  It may be your stored procedure has run but logic apps doesn't know about it? Will keep digging, but see if you can work it out too.  Microsoft....

Comment: It shuld not take so much time but can you please ensure if the gateway and the logic app are hosted in the same region and is the gateway started and connected?

Comment: Guys, thank you all!
The problem was in parameters. If I set parameter as string variable from logic app and in my sql SP use this parameter as 'cast(@param as varchar(10))', all is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in parameters. If I set parameter as string variable from logic app and in my sql SP use this parameter as `cast(@param as varchar(10))`, all is ok.